# PHP MVC Cash Register

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a cash register system using PHP and MVC Architecture. Let me break down my code. It basically fetches the list of menu items and allows the user to select from them. So the purpose is to create an order and add items to it. The application must calculate the total price of items including the discount.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../models/CashRegisterModel.php';

class CashRegisterController
{
    private $db;
    private $cashRegister;
    private $order;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->cashRegister = new CashRegisterModel();

        session_start();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['order'])) {
            $_SESSION['order'] = [];
        }
        $this->order = $_SESSION['order'];
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $menuItems = $this->cashRegister->menuItems();
        if (isset($_GET['cancelOrder']) && $_GET['cancelOrder'] === 'true') {

            $this->order = [];
            $_SESSION['order'] = $this->order;
            $totalPrice = 0;
            echo 'Order has been canceled.';

        } 
        else {
            // Initialize total price
            $totalPrice = 0;
            $discount = 0;

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                if (isset($_POST['submitItems']) || isset($_POST['completeOrder'])) {
                    $selectedMenuItems = isset($_POST['menuItemsSelect']) ? $_POST['menuItemsSelect'] : [];
                    $quantities = isset($_POST['quantities']) ? $_POST['quantities'] : [];

                    // Add the selected items with quantities to the order array
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($selectedMenuItems); $i++) {
                        $menuItem = $selectedMenuItems[$i];
                        $quantity = $quantities[$i];

                        // Fetch the price of the item from your CashRegisterModel
                        $get_price = $this->cashRegister->getPrice($menuItem);
                        $price = $quantity * $get_price;
                        $name = $this->cashRegister->getname($menuItem);

                        // Ensure that the order item is an array
                        $orderItem = [
                            'id' => $menuItem,
                            'item' => $name,
                            'quantity' => $quantity,
                            'price' => $price
                        ];

                        // Add the order item to the order array
                        $this->order[] = $orderItem;
                    }

                    // Calculate the total price by summing up all prices in the order
                    $totalPrice = array_sum(array_column($this->order, 'price'));
                    $result = $this->calculateDiscountedPrice();
    
                    $_SESSION['order'] = $this->order;
                    $order = $this->order;
                    if (isset($_POST['completeOrder'])) {
                        $this->completeOrder();

                    }
                    $this->printBill($order,$result);
                    $this->viewItems($order,$result);

                }

            }
            include 'views/register/CashRegister.php';
        }
    }

    
    public function completeOrder()
    {                    
        
            $result = $this->calculateDiscountedPrice();
            $discountedPrice = $result['discountedPrice'];
            echo 'discountedPrice: ' . $discountedPrice;
            $orderID = $this->cashRegister->insert_order($discountedPrice);
            echo 'Order completed with ID: ' . $orderID . $discountedPrice;

            // Store each order item in the database
            foreach ($this->order as $orderItem) {
                $menuItemID = $orderItem['id'];
                $quantity = $orderItem['quantity'];
                $itemPrice = $orderItem['price'];

                $this->cashRegister->insert_order_items($orderID, $menuItemID, $quantity, $itemPrice);
            }
            $this->cashRegister->insert_bill($orderID, 10, $discountedPrice);
            // Clear the order array and reset the total price
            $this->order = [];

            $_SESSION['order'] = $this->order;
    }
    

    private function printBill($order,$result)
    {   
        include 'views/register/bill.php';
    }

    private function viewItems($order,$result){
        $result = $this->calculateDiscountedPrice();

        include 'views/register/add.php';
        
    }

    private function calculateDiscountedPrice()
    {
        $totalPrice = array_sum(array_column($this->order, 'price'));
        $discount = isset($_POST['discount']) ? $_POST['discount'][0] : 0;
        $discountAmount = $totalPrice * ($discount / 100);
        $discountedPrice = $totalPrice - $discountAmount;

        return [
            'discountedPrice' => $discountedPrice,
            'discountAmount' => $discount,
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the view

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="menuItemsSelect[]">Select Menu Items:</label>
        <select class="w-full border rounded py-2 px-3" name="menuItemsSelect[]" id="menuItemsSelect" multiple>
            <option hidden="">Select Item</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($menuItems as $item) {
                echo '<option value="' . $item['id'] . '">' . $item['name'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="quantities[]">Quantity:</label>
        <input class="w-full border rounded py-2 px-3" type="number" name="quantities[]" id="quantities" min="1" value="1">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="discount">Discount:</label>
        <input class="w-full border rounded py-2 px-3" type="number" name="discount[]" id="discount" min="0" value="0">
    </div>


    <input class="bg-gray-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded" type="submit" name="submitItems" value="Submit Order">
    <a class="text-blue-500 hover:underline" href="?cancelOrder=true">Cancel Order</a>

    <input class="bg-green-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded" type="submit" name="completeOrder" value="Complete Order">
</form>
```

So let me run through the scenario and explain the problem in depth.So I select Pasta from the list of menu items and select the quantity to 1.The price for the pasta is $100. I add a 10% discount to the price and the total price is now $90. The code works fine up to here. Now when I hit complete order button, the discount value totally disappears and the code takes the total price before discount($100) and passes that instead.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this topic? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the discounted price:

```
$result = $this->calculateDiscountedPrice();
```

but `$result` is never written back to `$this->order`

so few ways to add the discounted array to your result, before saving it to Session are:

```php
$this->order['discounts'] = $this->calculateDiscountedPrice();
// or directly merge
$this->order = array_merge($this->order, $result);
```

Comment: I did this '''$order = $this->order = array_merge($this->order, $result);
                    echo 'Merged Order: <pre>';
                    print_r($order);
                    echo '</pre>';
''' and got the array. How how do I pass it to if (isset($_POST['completeOrder'])) {

                    } I tried using a session but it didn't work.

Comment: `function completeOrder()` can accept an argument passed to it, so `function completeOrder($order)` .. and then work with that array, similar to your other functions

Comment: I tried passing it, did a var_dump and got discountedPrice: 1111discountedPrice: 0NULL